# need to override a CSS background color

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

so I have the following

```
.select, 
.input, 
.schedule, 
.editableFields 
{
cursor: pointer;
background-color: blue;
}
```

and this overrides the following:

```
#past .layer.color {        
background-color: #E5D403 !important;   /*this needs to be the first priority color*/
 }
```

EDIT: If I just have this second CSS, it does work! But when I add the blue it colors all it needs to and OVERRIDES #past (I dont want it to do this!) 
But I need the second background-color to override the first background-color. I have tried giving it lots of IDs and lots of classes and also using !important, but nothing seems to work...please help! (I don't know if it matters, but I am also using twitter bootstrap, but I have all of my css rules in a custom.css)

I also tried adding an inline css to the html. There is a ton of html, so I'll just put the top part

```
<div class="accordionGroups">
            <div class="accordionHeading">
                <a class="accordion collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-parent="#mainAccordion" data-target="#collapseThree"> <i
                    class="twistyIcon"></i> Layers
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFirst" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner scrollable">
                    <ul id="layers-dropdown-menu">
                       <li><label class="checkbox" id="past"> <span class="layer color legend"></span> Past
                       </label></li>
```

as background-color:#E5D403 but it gave me an error and Im not sure why (maybe I put it in the wrong place in the html?)

The following doesn't work either:

```
.checkbox span .layer.color.legend
{
 background-color: #E5D403 !important;
}
```

Comment: post your full html code  where is class `.layer`

Comment: What's the first background color and the second one?

Comment: Those CSS rules are selecting different elements so one would not be overriding the other. Ensure you are selecting the correct element in your css

Comment: there is no overriding in the above css. Give the full html and explain yourself better.

Comment: @tusharGupta, I have posted the first part of my html. the entire file is huge, but this should be sufficient.

Comment: How is this html relevant to the rest of the question?  I see absolutely no correlation between css and markup.

Comment: I'm trying to make the id "past" (from the html) background color override the first css I have up there.

Comment: The `#past .layer.color` span doesn't actually contain anything.

Comment: but if i do not have the first background-color, it shows up perfectly. so it does contain it. I just need the past .layer.color to supersede the first css condition. the colors are for different situations.

Comment: I have edited my question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, guys. I couldn't fix this error from within the CSS. Since my page was being dynamically updated, I had to fix this in javascript, when I was creating each of the rows.

```
if(notYellowRow){
    $row.find('.select').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $row.find('.input').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $row.find('.schedule').css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work?

```
#past {        
   background-color: #E5D403 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed space between class

try this

HTML

```
 <span class="legend"> TEXT HERE</span>
```

CSS

```
span.legend
{
 background-color: #E5D403 !important;
}
```

Comment: `.layer .color` means an element with the class `color` inside an element with the class `layer`.  `.layer.color` means an element that has both classes.

Comment: @Archer, his initial HTML shown layer class wraps color class. So I advised him to use in such a way#

Comment: He's never posted any html with those class names, and besides, my comment was directed at your answer before you modified it.

Comment: This does not work either. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: @user2847749, updated the answer with HTML and CSS. `Your text is not inside span`.

Comment: @Murali, the ID is within the span. The text is merely a label

Answer (score 0):

`.layer.color` refers to an element that is empty, and therefore does not take up any screen space.

What should the output look like? If you have an image of what you're expecting, we might be able to help you more.

Sans that, if you want "Past" to have the new background color, you need to put it inside the span's tags - `<span class="layer color legend">Past</span>`

Comment: You can put a picture up on Photobucket or some other external image host and link to it. I also recommend getting a jsfiddle.net post up that shows the behaviors you're seeing. The code you've provided doesn't even give me the goldenrod color if I do it myself.